# How do I mock a DataTransfer item for testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, testing-library

I am trying to use [Testing-library user-event paste](https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/#pasteelement-text-eventinit-options) to test an `onPaste` event handler for a react component.

The event handler:

```
pasteHandler = (event: any) => {
    const text = event.clipboardData.getData("text");
    parseAndUpdateState(text);
}
```

If I try `const clipboardData = new DataTransfer();` or a global mock as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54864280/how-to-mock-datatransfer-with-jest)
I get: `Error: Uncaught [ReferenceError: DataTransfer is not defined].`

No matter how I try to define either a mock jest object or create my own definition, I get errors for either missing dataTransfer object or missing fields.

Is there a something I am missing for how to mock out a DataTransfer object where I just need to get clipboard data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [Article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/2-ways-to-trigger-the-onpaste-event-with-testing-library-1502c5fdb9e) from [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66144715/how-to-paste-clipboard-data-using-react-testing-library)

I missed the documentation for [createEvent](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/#createeventeventname) and after using that along with

```
  const PhoneNumberElement = screen.queryByTestId('paste-input');

  const paste = createEvent.paste(PhoneNumberElement, {
    clipboardData: {
      getData: () => '123456',
    },
  });

  fireEvent(PhoneNumberElement, paste);
```

as mentioned in the article I was able to paste and trigger the onPaste handler.